# Using STRPOS with a redirect

Tags: php

I have built a small piece of middle layer code that checks for the existence of a string and redirects users based on its existence. The string is the word 'recovery' and Im using strpos to check a variable as follows:

```
if (isset($_GET["record"])) {
    $_SESSION["record"] = $_GET["record"];
}

if (strpos($record,'Recovery') !== false) {
   header('Location: cat_recovery.php');
    //echo 'growth';
}else{
    //header('Location: item_view_cust.php');
    header('Location: cat_growth.php');
}
```

I am also setting a SESSION variable because Im passing the info to other pages after the redirect. Currently, everything is being redirected to cat_growth.php even though the incoming POST variable 'record' includes 'Recovery'

I have tried the following based on the SESSION as well:

```
if (strpos($_SESSION['record'],'Recovery') !== false) {
   header('Location: cat_recovery.php');
    //echo 'growth';
}else{
    //header('Location: item_view_cust.php');
    header('Location: cat_growth.php');
}
```

**EDIT added for added clarity:**

The variables are coming from the previous URL like such:

```
  <a href="middle.php?name=<?php echo $name;  ?>&id=<?php echo $id1;  ?>&rowid=<?php echo $rowid;  ?>&record=<?php echo $record;  ?>">
```

The variables are passing properly and have been checked with print_r in the page I posted.

Im searching for 'Recovery' with a capitol R.

Yes session_start(); is being utilized properly.

Comment: So where is `$record` set? Is the word you're looking for `Recovery` or `recovery`? And is it in `$_POST` (you say post, but are testing get) or `$_GET`?

Comment: What is the value of $_SESSION['record'] ?

Comment: Is the string "recovery" or "Recovery"? I see both in your post.

Comment: do you have `session_start()`?

Comment: Any hints from your error log?

Comment: I edited my post to answer everyone's questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, in theory. It does when I rerun it in my own local PHP dev environment. Here's how I'd recommend debugging. Somewhere in the following process you will echo or var_dump a value that you don't expect and that will allow you to pinpoint your precise problem:

1) First echo the GET variable value to yourself as follows. Note that I like to add pipe (|) characters around my echo text since it makes it easier to tell if the value is truly blank, a space, has leading/trailing space, etc.

```
if (isset($_GET["record"])) {
    echo '|' . $_GET["record"] . '|';
    $_SESSION["record"] = $_GET["record"];
}

if (strpos($record,'Recovery') !== false) {
   header('Location: cat_recovery.php');
}else{
    header('Location: cat_growth.php');
}
```

2) If the echo data looks exactly like you want ("|Recovery|", no leading or trailing spaces) then move on to doing a similar echo for the SESSION variable after you set it.

```
if (isset($_GET["record"])) {
    $_SESSION["record"] = $_GET["record"];
    echo '|' . $_SESSION["record"] . '|';
}

if (strpos($record,'Recovery') !== false) {
   header('Location: cat_recovery.php');
}else{
    header('Location: cat_growth.php');
}
```

3) If the echo data looks exactly like you want ("|Recovery|", no leading or trailing spaces) then move on to doing a similar echo for the $record variable right before you test it in the code. There's a chance this could be the problem if your server doesn't have PHP configured with `register_globals=on`, which would mean the `$record` variable is not automatically created for you and you have not specifically created it or set its value in the code you provided.

```
if (isset($_GET["record"])) {
    $_SESSION["record"] = $_GET["record"];
}

echo '|' . $record . '|';

if (strpos($record,'Recovery') !== false) {
   header('Location: cat_recovery.php');
}else{
    header('Location: cat_growth.php');
}
```

4) If the echo data looks exactly like you want ("|Recovery|", no leading or trailing spaces) then move on to using var_dump on the value produced by the strpos test. I'd use var_dump here because you want to know if the value returned is boolean FALSE or integer 0, the difference between which is crucial in this situation.

```
if (isset($_GET["record"])) {
    $_SESSION["record"] = $_GET["record"];
}

var_dump(strpos($record,'Recovery'));

if (strpos($record,'Recovery') !== false) {
   header('Location: cat_recovery.php');
}else{
    header('Location: cat_growth.php');
}
```

Does it spit out a number `int(0)` like you expect or does it spit out `bool(false)` which means no match was found?

This methodical approach should lead you to the problem. Might seem like you are testing things you don't need to test by starting from such basic elements, but the basic elements can be out of whack in ways you'd never expect until you explicitly test.

Hope this helps. If you discovery more info or solve the problem I'd be interested to know what you find.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed process. Ill let you know what I find!